# Roughly measure vacuum pressure without sensor

Tags: vacuum

How would you identify various levels of vacuum, without a calibrated, dedicated vacuum/pressure sensor?  For instance, my understanding is that a Crooke's Radiometer only works in certain ranges of vacuum.  Liquids boil at temperatures different from normal, high voltages exhibit different behaviors and appearances (and cease) at different pressures, and so forth.

An ideal answer might be a table or annotated scale mapping vacuum ranges to different phenomena and vice versa, perhaps including links to demonstrations of said phenomena (though such should be fairly easily googled).  The broader the range of identifiable vacuum, the more phenomena given, and (to the extent possible) the finer the "resolution" of identification, the better.  (Less credit, but still some, given for tests requiring extremely rare and hard-to-come-by materials or equipment.)

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at. You need an apparatus of some sort to measure pressure. You don't want a calibrated sensor. You want a sensor that isn't calibrated? For example, water boils a room temperature below a certain pressure. That sounds like what you want. But if you use a calibrated thermometer so you know if it is at room temperature, that doesn't. I am not sure I see the point of excluding the kind of sensor you would actually use.

Comment: @mmesser314 Sorry - I meant no VACUUM sensors.  Pirani gauges, ion gauges, thermocouple gauges, etc., none of those.  Thermometers, multimeters, etc. are fine - question is basically "how to measure a vacuum, without vacuum gauges".  I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you're making the distinction between a vacuum sensor and everything else.  Anything that is used to measure a vacuum is a vacuum sensor.  If you run current through a filament at constant voltage, the ambient gas will absorb heat from the filament, decreasing its temperature and therefore its resistance.  Different pressures would mean different resistances, so this would measure the vacuum level.  It uses only a multimeter and a current source, but if you do this then you've just built a Pirani gauge for yourself.